# Retrieving data from a reader and saving it in a double variable

Tags: sql, .net

I'm making a project to issue tickets to a company.For this,I use a table to store the price of a ticket of adults and children.

[image]

[image]

In my program,I use a reader to retrieve these values in the table and save them to decimal variables.Here is the code.(adult-number of adult tickets,child-number of child tickets,adprice-price of an adult ticket,chprice-price of a child ticket.)

```
            adult= Double.Parse(txtadult.Text);
            child = Double.Parse(txtchild.Text);
            con.Open();
            String select_query_pri = "SELECT Adult,Child FROM Price WHERE No= 1 ";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(select_query_pri, con);
            SqlDataReader R = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (R.Read())
            {
                adprice = R.GetDouble(0);
                chprice = R.GetDouble(1);
            }
            con.Close();
            tot = (adult * adprice) + (child * chprice);
            txttotal.Text = tot.ToString();
```

Then I'm using another double variable to calculate the total of the tickets and then it is displayed in the program.But when the program is executed,an error appears saying "Specified cast is not valid".

[image]

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following lines;

```
adprice = Convert.ToDouble(R[0]);
chprice = Convert.ToDouble(R[1]);
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine!Thank You!!